# Initializing OmniAuth with unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth, unicorn, production

I have a rails 3 app which uses OminAuth. I'm initializing It with the file "config/initializers/omniauth.rb":

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, "...", "..."
  provider :identity, :on_failed_registration => lambda { |env| IdentitiesController.action(:new).call(env) }

  OmniAuth.config.on_failure = Proc.new { |env|
    OmniAuth::FailureEndpoint.new(env).redirect_to_failure
  }
end
```

It works normally on development using WEBrick, but on production (nginx + unicorn) the app hangs and unicorn.log shows the following:

```
E, [2013-04-11T14:45:41.485066 #3276] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 18825 exit 1> worker=1
I, [2013-04-11T14:45:41.485439 #3276]  INFO -- : worker=1 spawning...
I, [2013-04-11T14:45:41.491241 #18831]  INFO -- : worker=1 spawned pid=18831
I, [2013-04-11T14:45:41.491662 #18831]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
E, [2013-04-11T14:45:41.622456 #18828] ERROR -- : uninitialized constant OmniAuth (NameError)
/home/insidegui/apps/curtaavida/releases/20130411173917/config/initializers/omniauth.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/insidegui/apps/curtaavida/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:588:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/home/insidegui/apps/curtaavida/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `each'
/home/insidegui/apps/curtaavida/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/home/insidegui/apps/curtaavida/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/home/insidegui/apps/curtaavida/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/home/insidegui/apps/curtaavida/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/insidegui/apps/curtaavida/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/home/insidegui/apps/curtaavida/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/home/insidegui/apps/curtaavida/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
/home/insidegui/apps/curtaavida/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/home/insidegui/apps/curtaavida/releases/20130411173917/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
config.ru:4:in `require'
config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
```

My production.log stays clean.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I stopped the unicorn process and started it again and now It works. I did a new cap:deploy and It seems to be working just fine now... strange...